# Flutter - Save Multiple Widget Transformation Before setState

Tags: flutter, dart, matrix, mobile, pinchzoom

I have a Stack with multiple MatrixGesture Containers with images that can be drag around, pinch zoom and rotate. I want to save the state of each container in the position and shape that it is, because after a little change using setState, everything go back to the original position.
All the information of the images is in a List with a specific object type.
Here is a snippet of the code to display the images:

```
class NewOutfitState extends State<NewOutfit> {
    List<DisplayGarment> garmentsList;
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("New"), 
        body:  new Container(
        child:MyList(myList: garmentsList, canvasSize: realCanvas,);
        )
    }
}
class MyListState extends State<MyList>{
    List<DisplayGarment> myList;
    double realCanvas;
    bool flag=false;
    int touch=0;
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        myList=widget.myList;
        realCanvas = widget.canvasSize;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
        children: getList(),
        );
    }

    List<Widget> getList(){
        List<Widget> listWidget=[];
        
        for(int i=0;i<myList.length;i++) {
        final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier1= ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
        DisplayGarment _garments = myList[i];
        
        listWidget.add( 
            MatrixGestureDetector(
            key: Key(i.toString()),
            onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) { 
            notifier1.value = m;
            },
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: notifier1,
            builder: (ctx, child) {
                return Transform(
                transform: notifier1.value,
                child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Container(          
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5),
                        child: 
                            Container(   
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),  
                            height: imgHeigh,
                            width: imgWidth,
                            child:
                                DottedBorder(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                strokeWidth: 0,
                                child: Center(
                                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl: 
                                    'https://fashiers.com/garments_img/'+imgUrl,
                                    height: imgHeigh,
                                    width: imgWidth,
                                )),
                            );   
                        ,)
                    )
                ],),);},),
            )
        );
    }
    return listWidget;
}
```

}

Also is it possible to set a border around the image when that is tap on and remove border on other that was probably tap before?

I appreciate any help with this.[image: first is the initial state and second is after been modify]

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you should not put `notifier1` initialization inside the build function. That's why every time you use `setStatus`, your position reset. This part should be initialize inside `initState()` and that means you should keep all garments location value in this class. (e.g. `List<ValueNotifier>`)

Second part, indexing the `garments` may be the instinctive solution. Display/Hide border by:

```
child: _selectedIndex == i ?
  // Widget with border
  : //Widget without border
```

and set `_selectedIndex` inside `onMatrixUpdate()`

Comment: Thanks a lot I am going to try solution with the notifier and the List. The only thing I am not getting is the _selectedIndex is it an int var or is it a widget? it should be a child of the MatrixGesture?

Comment: In the code above, `_selectedIndex` is it an int var and can be defined in class level. Because I see the for loop about `i` in your `getList()` function and try to reuse it. You can define your own way to indexing it.